# A Function to Test if `get-in` will Succeed

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, standard-library

In Clojure/Script the `contains?` function can be used to check if a subsequent `get` will succeed. I believe that the Clojure version will do the test without retrieving the value. The ClojureScript version uses `get` and *does* retrieve the value.

Is there an equivalent function that will test whether a path through a map, as used by `get-in`, will succeed? That does the test without retrieving the value?

For example, here is a naive implementation of `contains-in?` similar to the ClojureScript version of `contains?` that retrieves the value when doing the test.:

```clj
(def attrs {:attrs {:volume {:default "loud"}
                    :bass   nil
                    :treble {:default nil}}})

(defn contains-in? [m ks]
  (let [sentinel (js-obj)]
    (if (identical? (get-in m ks sentinel) sentinel)
      false
      true)))

(defn needs-input? [attr-key]
  (not (contains-in? attrs [:attrs attr-key :default])))

(println "volume: needs-input?: " (needs-input? :volume))
(println "  bass: needs-input?: " (needs-input? :bass))
(println "treble: needs-input?: " (needs-input? :treble))

;=>volume: needs-input?:  false
;=>  bass: needs-input?:  true
;=>treble: needs-input?:  false
```

Anything in the map of "attributes" that does not contain a default value requires user input. (`nil` is an acceptable default, but a missing value is not.)

Comment: Why do you ask for "That does the test without retrieving the value"? The expensive part is doing the key lookups; once you've done that, getting the value out is free.

Comment: @amalloy: Curiosity. It seems that Clojures implementation goes to an awful lot of bother and I just wondered why.

Comment: @Alan: The use case is pretty similar to the example but with deeper maps. One person defines a type of document, including characteristics it must have, should have, should not have, etc. Other people are tasked with writing those types of documents. The step illustrated here is to create a set of rules that can be applied to the documents as written by the second group. In addition to the validation, it should give useful error messages and guidance.

Comment: It feels like you're reinventing clojure.spec at this point...?

Comment: @sean: You may be right. I've never used it. I'll look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn contains-in? [m ks]
  (let [ks (seq ks)]
    (or (nil? ks)
        (loop [m m, [k & ks] ks]
          (and (try
                 (contains? m k)
                 (catch IllegalArgumentException _ false))
               (or (nil? ks)
                   (recur (get m k) ks)))))))
```

---

BTW, looking at the relevant functions in [the source of `clojure.lang.RT`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java), I noticed that the behavior of `contains?` and `get` can be a bit buggy when their first argument is a string or Java array, as is illustrated below:

```
user=> (contains? "a" :a)
IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type: java.lang.String
user=> (contains? "a" 0.5)
true
user=> (get "a" 0.5)
\a
user=> (contains? (to-array [0]) :a)
IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type: [Ljava.lang.Object;
user=> (contains? (to-array [0]) 0.5)
true
user=> (get (to-array [0]) 0.5)
0
user=> (contains? [0] :a)
false
user=> (contains? [0] 0.5)
false
user=> (get [0] 0.5)
nil
```